# onSuccess not triggering while using uxMode='redirect' ->react-google-login?

Tags: reactjs, google-signin

I am using react-google-login component to make user login through google account I have an issue in that.  If I use **uxMode='popup'**

onSucess method is triggering but the same method is not triggering if i use uxMode='redirect'
`

```
    <GoogleLogin
clientId="*****"
scope= "profile"
buttonText="Login with Google"
uxMode='redirect'
redirectUri="http://localhost:3000"
onSuccess={responseGoogle}
onFailure={responseGoogle}/>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed adding the trailing slash i.e / to

1)redirectUri i.e redirectUri="http://localhost:3000/"

2)Also make sure that you have added trailing slash i.e / in Authorized redirect URIs under https://console.developers.google.com/. It should also be http://localhost:3000/

```js
<GoogleLogin
clientId="*****"
scope= "profile"
buttonText="Login with Google"
uxMode='redirect'
redirectUri="http://localhost:3000/"
onSuccess={responseGoogle}
onFailure={responseGoogle}/>`
```

Do not miss the trailing slash.

Comment: Not working as expected and not redirecting

Answer (score 0):

the redirectUri you specify, should be the one you authorized for the OAuth client. means while creating your app id in google developer console you have to whitelist that url

Comment: In Authorized redirect URIs I have entered that specified url  .   If so atleast onFailure should have called ???

Comment: failure will be called if login is not successful. but in your case login in successful but redirect is the problem so you might be getting some error on screen from google

Comment: ya crt but still its not triggered , i am able to redirect to next page but for saving the details i couldn't call a function

Answer (score 0):

then remove redirect here and redirect from your code after saving the details. for your reference am pasting my code below.

```
<GoogleLogin
                  clientId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                  buttonText="Login with Google"
                  uxMode="redirect"
                  redirectUri="http://localhost:3000"
                  onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                  onFailure={responseGoogle}
                />
```

am calling this from http://localhost:3000/results page and its redirecting to http://localhsot:3000/#id_token=XXXX with appending id_token on my url.

Comment: nope how come to do so   we can't give uxMode='redirect' without specifying redirectUri

Comment: if you dont give redirectUri, it will redirect back to the same page. there you can handle the responseGoogle and then redirect from your code. note: your current page also need to be whitelisted

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did with redirect mode..  Onsuccess Function will never be called.. instead use query string and get parsed # id_token.. and send it to server for further validation and profile data